# Cert-managed with wilcard and Cloudflare DNS, stuck at 'OrderCreated'

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I'm trying to get cert-manager and letsencrypt working for a wildcard domain. I've pointed the wildcard A host to the load balancer IP (GKE). Here is the secret and issuer:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudflare-api-key
  namespace: cert-manager
type: Opaque
data:
  apikey: BASE_64_ENCODED_API_KEY
---
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: EMAIL
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          cloudflare:
            email: EMAIL
            apiKeySecretRef:
              name: cloudflare-api-key
              key: apikey
```

and here is my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apps-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "*.sampledomain.com"
      secretName: letsencrypt-staging
  rules:
    - host: phpmyadmin.sampledomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: phpmyadmin
              servicePort: 8081
```

The events are stuck at 'OrderCreated'. On checking the logs:

```
E0817 08:42:45.872348       1 base_controller.go:189] cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Cloudflare API Error \n\t Error: 9103: Unknown X-Auth-Key or X-Auth-Email" "key"="default/letsencrypt-staging-3055668421-0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in my email address :|